# Is it possible to use Linq .IndexOf() in SQL Server database ? - Alternative to .Contains()

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Does anyone know a way to use/ if its possible

```
.IndexOf()
```

in SQL Server instead of

```
.Contains()
```

Currently I get a `NotSupportedException`:

> The translation of String.IndexOf to SQL does not support versions with a StringComparison argument

I would like to have something better performing than `.Contains(ToLower(string))`.

This is what I tried:

```
.Where(b => b.item.IndexOf(boSearchTerm, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)!= -1)
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect that to do? Do you have some SQL you are trying to replicate?

Comment: Ah, the mysterious and omnipresent *SQL DB*

Comment: I would like to avoid using ToLower() in a .Cointains() and I'm looking for something like:
 .Where(b => b.xxxx.IndexOf(boSearchTerm, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)!=-1)

Comment: The error is _very_ specific and clear (especially when compared to the question which fails to mention the type involved). If you want to use `string.IndexOf` you may not use a `StringComparison` because that is not supported

Comment: @Plutonix You can also use Linq on a NoSql DB ....

Comment: @DanielOhne Plutonix meant "we need to know the exact database provider you are using"

Comment: @Aluan Thank you, that is right. I thought maybe there is a simple alternative. The type is mentioned in the exception that you can see in the question...

Comment: @Camillo Sorry about that: MS SQL 2012

Answer (score 3):

The concept of `StringComparison` cannot be translated to SQL because databases use more specific concept of [collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support). To do a case insensitive comparison, use a case insensitive collation at storage (instance, database or column definition) or force a specific collation in the comparison, see [Casting Collation of an Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations). The collation to be used is entirely specific on the national type of the data used.

Also, using `ToLower()` is incorrect in C# and in any other language of choice. It will [not pass](https://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-turkey/) the [Turkish I test](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html).

Answer (score 0):

Set the collation of your column to CI (case-insensitive) and the Contains will be case insensitive... – Wouter Huysentruit 1 min ago

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to ignore casing in your SQL queries is to set the collation of the column to CI (case-insensitive), that way `Contains` or any other string comparison will be case-insensitive.

If you want to improve this lookup, you can also add a [FULLTEXT INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql) on the column.